# How do I get the data from two different collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am having two different collections:

**userimage:**

```
> db.userimage.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e67ee06eeab5ff79cdbf"), "transactionid" : 200, "age" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e730e06eeab5ff79cdc0"), "transactionid" : 100, "age" : 28 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e737e06eeab5ff79cdc1"), "transactionid" : 300, "age" : 29 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e741e06eeab5ff79cdc2"), "transactionid" : 400, "age" : 32 }
```

**usertest**

```
> db.usertest.find()
{ "_id" : 100, "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : 200, "name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : 300, "name" : "C" }
{ "_id" : 400, "name" : "D" }
```

Here transactionid of userimage is releated to _id of usertest collection..How can i reference both the collection..  *Is there any better ways of designing these two collection...*
I dont want to keep both the collection in one collection due to some reason..

I want to do it using java code:

Below is what I am trying to do::

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "ITAU" );
        userimage = db.getCollection("userimage");
        usertest = db.getCollection("usertest");
        BasicDBObject post = new BasicDBObject("transactionid", 200);
        DBCursor myCur = userimage.find(post);
        while(myCur.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(myCur.next());

        }
```

How can i get both the collection data...

Comment: why you should not add `usertest` `name` field in `userimage` collection ?

Comment: No.There is a reason behind this..I will keep some image file..So I want to keep seperatly..

Comment: You can use a scripting language like python and pymongo and create two unique connections and iterate through them at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `usertest` collection `name` field not required then add `name` field`in`userimage`collection so`userimage` collection looks like this :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e67ee06eeab5ff79cdbf"), "transactionid" : 200, "age" : 30 ,"name":"B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e730e06eeab5ff79cdc0"), "transactionid" : 100, "age" : 28 ,"name":"A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e737e06eeab5ff79cdc1"), "transactionid" : 300, "age" : 29 ,"name":"C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e741e06eeab5ff79cdc2"), "transactionid" : 400, "age" : 32 ,"name":"D" }
```

then used your code as :

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "ITAU" );
    userimage = db.getCollection("userimage");
    usertest = db.getCollection("usertest");
    BasicDBObject post = new BasicDBObject("transactionid", 200);
    DBCursor myCur = userimage.find(post);
    while(myCur.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(myCur.next());
    }
```

It return whole matching documents of given conditions. If is not possible to move `name` filed in `userimage` collection then you should do two separate while loop like this :

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "ITAU" );
    userimage = db.getCollection("userimage");
    usertest = db.getCollection("usertest");
    BasicDBObject post = new BasicDBObject("transactionid", 200);
    BasicDBObject _idPost = new BasicDBObject("_id", 200); // because _id = transactionid
    DBCursor myCur = userimage.find(post);
    DBCursor myCur1 = usertest.find(_idPost);
    while(myCur.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(myCur.next());
    }
    while(myCur1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(myCur1.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using NoSQL database not RDBMS. Joins are not supported in MongoDB. So, it's better if you can merge collections and change your schema like:

`userimage` collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e67ee06eeab5ff79cdbf"), "transactionid" : 200, "age" : 30 }
```

`usertest` collection:

```
{ "_id" : 200, "name" : "B" }
```

Better to use-

say `user` collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5590e67ee06eeab5ff79cdbf"), "transactionid" : 200, "age" : 30, "name" : "B" }
```

*Here, I am assuming one to one relationship. If there is one to many, you can keep a list of it.*

For more details, Plese [refer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/).

Comment: No.There is a reason behind this..I will keep some image file..So I want to keep seperatly.

Comment: if image files are of larger sizes, then you can look into [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) too.